# What is the number of triangle formations for n rows?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

We have n rows and $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ students, each student has a distinct height starting from 1 to $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$, we will make the first row has n student, second row has $n - 1$ students, third row has $n - 2$ and so on until we end up with one student in the last row.
we have one condition that is no taller student is standing in front of another shorter student, and no taller student is standing to the left of another shorter student. In other words we want to make each row increasing from left to right and each column increasing from bottom to top.
For example if $n = 3$ we have 6 students of heights $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ .
A valid formation may look like this: 
4 5 6 
2 3 
1

So we want to count the number of such valid formations.
Sorry for bad formatting and any mistakes. 
 
I encountered this problem on a facebook group related to algorithms field, someone asked for help but we didn't know how to find the solution. 
I tried to solve it and made some observations that might be helpful to find the solution or not, I don't know in fact. 
First let's assume the rows are numbered from 1 to n from top to bottom and columns are numbered from 1 to n from left to right. 
Let's denote a a cell at row i and column j by a[i][j]

1. a[i][j] is greatest number in the block that starts at the bottom left and ends at a[i][j]. for n = 3 in the above example, 5 is greatest number in (5, 4, 2, 3, 1), 3 is the greatest number in (3, 2, 1).
2. a[i][j] is the smallest number in the block starting from a[i][j] and ends at top right cell. 1 is the smallest number in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 4 is the smallest number in (4, 5, 6).
3. In any valid formation the numbers 1 and $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ are always fixed in a[n][1] and a[1][n]. why? by the first observation : a[n][0] is the smallest element in the entire grid, so it can't have any number other than 1, by the second observation a[1][n]  is the greatest element the entire grid so it can't have any number other than $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$
4. If n > 1 we have numbers 2 and $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} - 1$ and they are also fixed in the a[n - 1][1] and a[1][n - 1] respectively, we can use the same method in $3$ to prove it.

Comment: Your query, which is nicely formatted, has three problems: (1) lack of clarity, (2) lack of context, and (3) lack of detail.  I advise revising your query re these problems.  Addressing these comments one at a time ... see next comment

Comment: (1:clarity) Suppose you have (for example) 10 students, #'d 1 thru 10.  Exactly how many distinct valid formations are there, and what are they.  Please edit your query to answer this question.  ...see next comment.

Comment: (2:context) Is this problem from (for example) a contest, book, or class.  If from a book or class, please briefly describe the theorems or pertinent (solved) problems/exercises in your book/class that lead up to this problem that you think might function as tools to be used in attacking the problem.  ...see next comment

Comment: (3:detail) If you haven't already done so, please spend at least 30 minutes to an hour trying to solve the problem on your own.  Make careful note re your methods of attack and what problems that you are encountering.  Then edit your query to provide full details re your efforts and the problems that you are encountering.

Comment: @user2661923: The question is perfectly clear, and exhibiting the half dozen acceptable formations for $n=4$ isn’t going to make it any clearer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Perhaps I am missing something.  When I read the query, and saw his example for $n=3$, I thought that the formation that he displayed was the only valid one.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the query or didn't read it closely enough.  For example, if $n=3$, what other valid formation is there?

Comment: @user2661923: $$\begin{array}{ccc}3&5&6\\2&4\\1\end{array}$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good catch, I totally missed that.  You're right, the problem is perfectly clear.

Comment: @maghrabyJr Brian M. Scott's comments resolved my question re clarity.  I totally withdraw that specific criticism from my remarks to you.  I apologize; for some reason, I simply wasn't grasping the problem until Brian Scott explained it to me.

Comment: @user2661923: By the way, please ignore *the half dozen* in my first comment: I seriously undercounted the $n=4$ case!

Comment: *hook length formula*

Comment: @RobPratt: I could be missing something, but if I’m not mistaken, the fact that the columns are decreasing rules out a straightforward application of the hook length formula.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003121

Comment: @user2661923 I have already tried solving it for more than 4 hours, I will edit it to put some observations I found out, thank you for you helpful comments.

Comment: @John Omielan: I edited the question including some back ground information and my effort to solve it. How can you reopen it again?

Comment: @maghrabyJr  "...How can you reopen it again?"  To the best of my knowledge, the query was **never closed.**  Certainly, as I am commenting, the query is open.  Closing a query is a somewhat extreme measure that requires that several mathSE users individually vote to close.  Further, only mathSE users that have a high reputation are authorized to vote to close.  For example, my reputation=1600 is not high enough, so I am not authorized to vote to close.

Comment: I looked at a couple of the references at the OEIS link that **RobPratt** posted above. Apart from the trivial change of turning the formation upside down, [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028989731) [PDF] deals with precisely this question. [This one](https://oeis.org/A005118/a005118.pdf) [PDF] deals with a more general problem and is in French, but it does illustrate this case at the end (Fig. $6$) and shows that the number of acceptable formations is $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ times the number of standard Young tableaux of the same shape.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you for your efforts, this is very helpful.

Comment: @maghrabyJr: You’re welcome.